# CUDA 6.5, Mathematica 10.0.2, and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cuda

I have CUDA 6.5 working well on Ubuntu 14.04. Mathematica recognizes the driver (Nvidia 340), but CUDAQ[] returns False and I cannot get any CUDA functions to work in Mathematica.

I have created symbolic links to /usr/lib64/ for the CUDA libraries.

Has anyone successfully gotten CUDA 6.5 to work with Mathematica in Ubuntu 14.04?

Note:  I have asked the same question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75585/cuda-6-5-mathematica-10-0-2-and-ubuntu-14-04) since this problem seems to me to be a Mathematica issue.  However, it is not entirely clear, so it seems prudent to ask the Ubuntu 14.04 community too.

Comment: Let me ask this:  In the directory /cuda-6.5/lib64, is the file libcuda.so there?  I have libcudart.so, is that the new name or a different library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The library file libcuda.so was in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

I just created a sym link there and Mathematica was able to find it and it is working fine now.